# Rails 3 and encrypted cookies with IE9

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, encryption, internet-explorer-9

I am using encrypted cookies to pass data to my rails app. Once these cookies get set, they are being passed just fine to my app from Chrome, Firefox, Safari (iOS and OSX version), etc.

However, the cookie isn't being passed back when I do the same on Win7/IE9.

I'm using Ruby 1.9 and Rails 3, and using the cookies.permanent.encrypted method of setting the cookie. E.g:

```
cookies.permanent.encrypted[:some_data] = object.some_data
```

Any ideas about what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it has to do with my P3P policy not getting passed correctly prior to the cookies being set. IE prevents cookies if that's the case, other browsers apparently don't care about that.

Comment: Yeah, how exactly you do it will depend on your web server. But I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy for thin clients. So I added this to my nginx.conf file:    
`add_header P3P 'CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"';`  
  
That P3p policy works for IE.